# PHP: Why functions can not avail the variables of a required file?

Tags: php, pdo, require

This is code is made to return the name of a chosen $ID from the database,

```
#DB Informations (username/password)
require('/path/to/db_informations.php');


# This function return the 'name of the $ID from the db
function getName($ID){
   $link = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pwd);

   $query = "SELECT `name` FROM `tables` WHERE `id`=$ID";

   $smt = $link->prepare($query);
   $smt->execute();
   $name = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   return $name['name'];
}

# db_informations contain the credentials to connect the database. ($dsn, $user, $pwd)
```

Mmh `require(/path/to/db_informations.php')` is not working inside the function even if I put `require();' function in the body. I do not understand my mistake, can you please explain me:

**Why the /path/to/file is not included by PHP? and How to?**

Comment: I suggest you read about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: parse your variables into the function and then return them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/285587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue.

`$dsn`, `$user`, `$pwd` are global variables and not defined within the `getName()` function scope.

The quickest way to resolve this is to use `global`.

```
function getName($ID) {
   global $dsn, $user, $pwd;
   // code...
}
```

However, I do not recommend using `global` (they are [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)). The better thing to do would be to define your database object (PDO) at the global scope and pass it around to your functions/classes. This is called [dependency injection](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-in-php/).

Comment: But If I had to retain a database connection open what should I use instead of global variable?

Comment: As I said, define your database object within the global scope, such from your *db_information* script. For start, you could simply move it outside the `getName()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your DB variables are not in scope of your getName() function. You need, at bare minimum:

```
function getName(...) {
   global $dsn, $user, $pwd;
   ...
}
```

In the greater picture, you should **NOT** be using global variables, nor should you be creating a DB connection in every function call. Connect to the database **ONCE** in your db setup file, then simply re-use that connection for the rest of the DB operations in your script.